# $pull from subschema with condition mongodb

Tags: mongodb

employeeStructureSchema.js

```
var employeeStructureSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('employeeSturctureModel', employeeStructureSchema);
```

companySchema.js

```
var employeeStructureSchema = require('./employeeStructureSchema.js').schema;

var companySchema = new Schema({
    companyName: String,
    phone: String,
    email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    companyAddress: String,
    settings: {
        "employees": [employeeSchema],
    },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('companies', companySchema);
```

My aim is to remove some employees whoever name starts with "dummy user" from settings.employees

i have tried following query. it is working. can you please suggest something

```
db.companies.update({"_id":objectId},{$pull:{"settings.employees":{ $elemMatch: {name: /^dummy user/}}}});
```

my single document is like this :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("563b35d1f07cc9d80a26436c"), 
    "settings" : {
        "employees" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("583d28253722e240103e0108"), 
                "name" : "dummy user"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("583d282e3722e240103e0109"), 
                "name" : "dummy user1"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("583d28403722e240103e010b"), 
                "name" : "dummy user2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your employee name is a type of list. You can try a query like this:

```
db.companies.update({},{$pull: {settings.employees.name: { $regex: '^dummy user'} }});
```

Since your schema is restricted, this query should work

```
  db.companies.update({},{
   '$pull': {
      'settings.employees': {
          'name':{ $regex: '^dummy user'}
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: when try your query, i am getting following error, cannot use the part (employees of settings.employees.name) to traverse the element

Comment: Can you post your single record

Comment: I added a sample document for your reference

Comment: $pull removes only the elements in the array that match the specified. employee.name is not an array.

Comment: i need to remove some sub documents inside "settings.employees" by checking "name". is there any operator that i can use mongoshell. because, i can't use node.js or mongoose in my case.

Comment: @SaravananK I have updated the query. I hope it helps.